# Why 'there cannot be more than one conformance, even with different conditional bounds'?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I hoped that Swift gives me the ability to create an extension for type with specified conditions in `where` block. I imagined that I can extend the same generic type with different extensions dependent on concrete generic type value (`T`). But not. Following example demonstrates my problem:

```swift
protocol P {    
    associatedtype Prop 
    var property: Prop { get }
}

enum E<T: P> {
   case single(T)
   case double(T)
}

extension E: P where T.Prop == Int {
   var property: Int {
      switch self {
      case .single(let o): return o.property
      case .double(let o): return o.property * 2
      }
   }
}

extension E: P where T.Prop == String {
   var property: String {
      switch self {
      case .single(let o): return o.property
      case .double(let o): return o.property + o.property
      }
   }
}

struct Int4: P {
   var property: Int {
       return 4
   }
}

struct StringHello: P {
    var property: String {
        return "Hello" 
    }
}

print(E.single(Int4()).property)
print(E.double(StringHello()).property)
```

Following error and note are the result of the compilation.

> error: conflicting conformance of 'E' to protocol 'P'; there cannot be more than one conformance, even with different conditional bounds
>   `extension E: P where T.Prop == String {`
>
> note: 'E' declares conformance to protocol 'P' here
>   `extension E: P where T.Prop == Int {`

Is it really impossible? Why? What can I do with my code to succeed?

---

Some details to demonstrate the problem in my real situation.
I have some generic enum, which is used with many different wrapped types.

```swift
enum Color<T> {
  case red(T), green(T)

  func map<T2>(_ transform: (T) -> T2) -> Color<T2> {
    switch self {
    case .red(let o): return .red(transform(o))
    case .green(let o): return .green(transform(o))
    }
  }
}
```

Very often, I need different extensions for Color to conform it to different protocols depending on the wrapped type. Sometimes these protocols have the same base (super) protocol and as a result, I have the current problem. Sometimes I cant extend Color to conform this base (super) protocol for all deriving protocols because I need different implementations.

Comment: Cool, you did something so insane you got an error message I've never seen before!!!!! Excellent

Comment: @matt I wouldn't say it's insane. It's a "tempting" direction to try to implement something, because its negative implications are relatively non-obvious

Comment: Maybe adventurous would be a better word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it impossible? Yes and no. It's not currently possible in Swift, as it has been implemented. It is in principle possible to be implemented.

The name for this is "overlapping conformances", and it was explicitly and purposely rejected. You can find the rationale in the "Alternatives considered" section of [SE-0143 Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md#overlapping-conformances). The TL;DR is: because it's really complicated.

Without knowing more about what exactly you were trying to use this for, there's not much direction we can provide.

Comment: I see the problem when the condition is based on `:`, but in my case, it is `==`. It is impossible to have `E` that confirm two conditions together `T.Prop == Int` and `T.Prop == String`.

Comment: Eh, that doesn't really make much of a difference. `T.Prop == Int` could be imagined as `T.Prop: _HiddenProtocolForInt`, with `protocol _HiddenProtocolForInt  {}` and `extension Int: _HiddenProtocolForInt {}`

Comment: @ValentineZakharenko You should tell us more about the problem you're trying to solve

Comment: It is impossible to describe my real situation it has too many details of project architecture (wrote after many long tries). I am using generics enums as an important part of the architecture to build something like syntax trees. Every time I need to extend generics enums. Of course, the sample can be redesigned. I think my concrete situation is out of the current question because it is over-detailed.

Comment: I added some details to demonstrate how it limits.

Answer (score 9):

As was described earlier you cannot just do this kind of extension. However, you can use hack like this:

```
protocol SomeExtension {
    func doSomething()
}

extension SomeExtension {
    func doSomething() {
        print("Do nothing or error")
    }
}

extension SomeExtension where Self == [String] {
    func doSomething() {
        print("String")
    }
}

extension SomeExtension where Self == [Int] {
    func doSomething() {
        print("Int")
    }
}

extension Array: SomeExtension { }

let stringsArr = ["a", "b", "d"]
let numbersArr = [1, 2, 3]
stringsArr.doSomething()
numbersArr.doSomething()
```

In console you can see

```
String
Int
```

Comment: Please elaborate - does this hack work because you're using a Sequence in the where condition?

Comment: No, this works because of an extension to a specific type. You can find an example with UIView and protocols here https://gist.github.com/PavlyukDev/e96a65cfd4ea2911c2a11a7d7186d2b0. I couldn't come up with anything, so if you have any ideas, please ask.

Comment: this works for direct call, but not work for call as SomeExtension

Comment: Good point. For `SomeExtension` it uses default implementation with "Do nothing or error" because the compiler shouldn't cast type `SomeExtesnion` to an array or something.