# Swift - KeyPath extension - enforce conformance to protocol

Tags: swift

ideally, I'd like to get the name of the property referenced by a KeyPath. But this seems not to be possible out-of-the-box in Swift.

So my thinking is that the KeyPath could provide this information based on protocol extension added by a developer.  Then I'd like to design an API with an initializer/function that accepts a KeyPath conforming to that protocol (that adds a computed property).

So far I was only able to define the protocol and conditional conformance of the protocol. The following code compiles fine.

```
protocol KeyPathPropertyNameProviding {
    var propertyName: String {get}
}

struct User {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

struct Person  {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

extension KeyPath: KeyPathPropertyNameProviding where Root == Person {
    var propertyName: String {
        switch self {
            case \Person.name: return "name"
            case \Person.age: return "age"
            default: return ""
        }
    }
}

struct PropertyWrapper<Model> {
    var propertyName: String = ""
    init<T>(property: KeyPath<Model, T>) {
        if let property = property as? KeyPathPropertyNameProviding {
            self.propertyName = property.propertyName
        }
    }
}

let userAge = \User.age as? KeyPathPropertyNameProviding
print(userAge?.propertyName) // "nil"
let personAge = \Person.age as? KeyPathPropertyNameProviding
print(personAge?.propertyName) // "age"

let wrapper = PropertyWrapper<Person>(property: \.age)
print(wrapper.propertyName) // "age"
```

But I am unable to restrict the API so that initialization parameter `property` has to be a KeyPath AND must conform to a certain protocol.

For example, the following would result in a compilation error but should work from my understanding (but probably I miss a key detail ;) )

```
struct PropertyWrapper<Model> {
    var propertyName: String = ""
    init<T>(property: KeyPath<Model, T> & KeyPathPropertyNameProviding) {
        self.propertyName = property.propertyName // compilation error "Property 'propertyName' requires the types 'Model' and 'Person' be equivalent"
    }
}
```

Any tips are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding conditional conformance. You seem to want to do this in the future:

```
extension KeyPath: KeyPathPropertyNameProviding where Root == Person {
    var propertyName: String {
        switch self {
            case \Person.name: return "name"
            case \Person.age: return "age"
            default: return ""
        }
    }
}

extension KeyPath: KeyPathPropertyNameProviding where Root == User {
    var propertyName: String {
        ...
    }
}

extension KeyPath: KeyPathPropertyNameProviding where Root == AnotherType {
    var propertyName: String {
        ...
    }
}
```

But you can't. You are trying to specify multiple conditions to conform to the same protocol. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282655/why-there-cannot-be-more-than-one-conformance-even-with-different-conditional) for more info on why this is not in Swift.

Somehow, one part of the compiler thinks that the conformance to `KeyPathPropertyNameProviding` is not conditional, so `KeyPath<Model, T> & KeyPathPropertyNameProviding` is actually the same as `KeyPath<Model, T>`, because somehow `KeyPath<Model, T>` already "conforms" to `KeyPathPropertyNameProviding` as far as the compiler is concerned, it's just that the property `propertyName` will only be available *sometimes*.

If I rewrite the initialiser this way...

```
init<T, KeyPathType: KeyPath<Model, T> & KeyPathPropertyNameProviding>(property: KeyPathType) {
    self.propertyName = property.propertyName
}
```

This *somehow* makes the error disappear and produces a warning:

> Redundant conformance constraint 'KeyPathType': 'KeyPathPropertyNameProviding'

Answer (score 0):

Key paths are hashable, so I recommend a dictionary instead. It's especially easy to put it together with strong typing if you're able to use a `CodingKey` type.

```swift
struct Person: Codable  {
  var name: String
  var age: Int

  enum CodingKey: Swift.CodingKey {
    case name
    case age
  }
}

extension PartialKeyPath where Root == Person {
  var label: String {
    [ \Root.name: Root.CodingKey.name,
      \Root.age: .age
    ].mapValues(\.stringValue)[self]!
  }
}
```

Then use parentheses instead of the cast you demonstrated. No need for a protocol so far…

```swift
(\Person.name).label // "name"
(\Person.age).label // "age"
```

This will probably all be cleaner due to built-in support someday. https://forums.swift.org/t/keypaths-and-codable/13945