# Swift Generic Classes and Extensions with Conditional Generics

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following class:

```swift
class MyClass<T: BaseClass> {

   let aThing = T()

   func someMethod() {
      configure()
   }
}
```

whereas

```swift
class SubTypeAOfBaseClass: BaseClass { ... }

class SubTypeBOfBaseClass: BaseClass { ... }
```

In `configure` I want to configure `aThing` depending on its type. Therefore I have created a protocol `Configurable` and an extension:

```swift
protocol Configurable {
   func configure()
}

extension MyClass: Configurable where T == SubTypeAOfBaseClass {
  func configure() {
     print("Configuring SubTypeAOfBaseClass")
     aThing.doSomethingA()
  }
}
```

The error that I get is in `MyClass.someMethod` where I call `configure()`: "Referencing instance method configure() requires types T and SubTypeAOfBaseClass be equivalent.

Another error when I add the following extension:

```swift
extension MyClass: Configurable where T == SubTypeBOfBaseClass {
  func configure() {
     print("Configuring SubTypeBOfBaseClass")
     aThing.doSomethingB()
  }
}
```

The error changes to "No exact matches in call to instance method configure" and in the line

```swift
extension MyClass: Configurable where T == SubTypeBOfBaseClass {
```

I get the error "Conflicting conformance of MyClass to protocol configurable, there cannot more than one conformance, even with different conditional bounds."

It *should* work, but apparently I am missing something or my understanding of how to achieve what I want is wrong.

Comment: Other issues aside, what if `T` is neither `SubTypeAOfBaseClass` nor `SubTypeBOfBaseClass`? For example, what if `T` is `BaseClass`?

Comment: Good question. I have no answer to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the case when `T` is `BaseClass`, or when `T` is `AnotherSubclass` that I defined as

```
class AnotherSubclass : BaseClass {

}
```

What would happen? You haven't declared a conformance to `Configure` when `T` is `AnotherSubclass`!

There's really only two (not bad) choices here.

1. You want `configure` to do nothing when `T` is neither `SubTypeAOfBaseClass` nor `SubTypeBOfBaseClass`
2. you only want `MyClass<SubTypeAOfBaseClass>` and `MyClass<SubTypeBOfBaseClass>` to be valid types - `MyClass<BaseClass>` and `MyClass<AnotherSubclass>` would give compiler errors.

Choice 2 is not possible in Swift. That would require something similar to the [sealed types in Java](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360) or Kotlin.

Choice 1 can be done like this:

```
class BaseClass {
    ...
    func configure() {
        
    }
}

class SubTypeAOfBaseClass: BaseClass {
    ...
    override func configure() {
        print("Configuring SubTypeAOfBaseClass")
        doSomethingA()
    }
}

class SubTypeBOfBaseClass: BaseClass {
    ...
    override func configure() {
        print("Configuring SubTypeAOfBaseClass")
        doSomethingB()
    }
}
class MyClass<T: BaseClass> {

   let aThing = T()

    func someMethod() {
        aThing.configure()
    }
}
```

You might notice that the each implementation of `configure` has been moved to the base classes. If you want to implement them all in `MyClass`, you must check the type by hand:

```
class MyClass<T: BaseClass> {

   let aThing = T()

    func someMethod() {
        if let selfA = self as? MyClass<SubTypeAOfBaseClass> {
            selfA.configure()
        } else if let selfB = self as? MyClass<SubTypeBOfBaseClass> {
            selfB.configure()
        }
    }
}

extension MyClass where T == SubTypeAOfBaseClass {
  func configure() {
     print("Configuring SubTypeAOfBaseClass")
     aThing.doSomethingA()
  }
}
extension MyClass where T == SubTypeBOfBaseClass {
  func configure() {
     print("Configuring SubTypeBOfBaseClass")
     aThing.doSomethingB()
  }
}
```

This is because of the second problem in your code - different parameterisations of a generic type, `MyClass<SubTypeAOfBaseClass>` and `MyClass<SubTypeBOfBaseClass>`, can't conform to a protocol *differently*. This is a limitation of Swift, unfortunately. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282655/why-there-cannot-be-more-than-one-conformance-even-with-different-conditional) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I need to implement `configure` in `MyClass` and can't do so in the sub-types. I was hoping for choice 2 actually. Maybe someday.